# MediaRecorder Crashing

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

MediaRecorder is crashing my app when I set the output file to a custom directory. If I set it to

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)` , it works completely fine.

**My Code:**

```
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16*44100);
                    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/My App/Voice/", new Date().getTime() + ".3gp");
                    recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

I made sure that my microphone as well as my reading and writing in storage permissions are allowed. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Error Log:

```
E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 4
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1378)
        at com.example.criminalscurse.Home$6.onTouch(Home.java:328)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13480)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:697)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3487)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:655)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13732)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6131)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5411)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5536)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5385)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5593)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5411)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5385)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8420)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8353)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8306)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8535)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:198)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.criminalscurse, PID: 5259
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1378)
        at com.example.criminalscurse.Home$6.onTouch(Home.java:328)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13480)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2904)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:697)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3487)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:655)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13732)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6131)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5411)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5536)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5385)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5593)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5411)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5385)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5358)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8420)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8353)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8306)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8535)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:198)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Post the error...

Comment: I think the error is in `MediaRecorder.stop()`. Are you sure that the problem is with the storage path?

Comment: Yes as I said when I set storage path to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), it works great

Answer (score 0):

Try whether this helps

```
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16*44100);
                    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyApp"+File.seperator+"Voice", new Date().getTime() + ".3gp");

                    
                    recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want it to be in Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC). I want the file to be in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/My App/Voice/", new Date().getTime() + ".3gp"