# Not able to get files from any Android folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-file

I am new in android and was trying to test something. I have this simple app, where I just want to read files from any android folder. Till now, I just checked how the paths are there which I came to know from the following

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

&

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

The paths obtained are like

```
/storage/emulated/0/ then rest of the folders
```

I have done everything, asked for permission in the manifest file, and in the app too. I check that even though the permission is granted and folder path is also correct but the `File.listFiles()` is givingme null pointer exception.

Please take a look at the code below:

**Permission in manfest file**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Code to get permission and try checking the files**

```
 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},101);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No permission yet",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Permission already granted",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
        File dcimPath = new File("/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth"); //This path is correct
        
        File[] files = dcimPath.listFiles(); // gives null pointer exception
        Log.i("files length ",files.length+"");
    }

     @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 101){
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Permission granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File dcimPath = new File("/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/"); 

            File[] files = dcimPath.listFiles(); //gives error
            Log.i("files length ",files.length+"");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Permission denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to `<application>` tag on the `Android Manifest` File

```
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

This is used to read `Shared Storage` apart from the app's private storage. Read [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-the-scoped-storage-in-android) if you are curious to know more...

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Wow. It worked. But Can you write some description like why is this the case? So that I can also accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @TahirHussainMir Happy to hear that. Updated answer...

Comment: Hi,
I have one more question. If you know the answer for that too, then I will write another question on stackoverflow and you can answer that too. My another question is regarding doze mode. I have one service in android and it stops automatically after the phone is locked for some time. How do I keep my service running? Thanks

Comment: can you please answer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098894/mediarecorder-crashing

Comment: @TahirHussainMir I had not worked with `Service` nor `Doze Mode`... Anyway post the question someone on Stack Overflow will answer it...

Comment: @Vishnu: To new users, it'd help to mention which part of the manifest file to add it to. There's `<application>`, `<activity>`, `<meta-data>` etc.